# Is there a way to somehow have both absolute position (bottom) and multiple of the same div side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, absolute

I am using divs as the bulding block for a sort of column graph. Each div takes up 1% of the screen and there's many of them. I want them to both stick to the bottom of their parent div via bottom: 0px; and somehow have multiple of them side by side using float:left; or display:inline;

I get either this with relative position and float: left; working

```
-----------------------
|IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII|
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------
```

Or this with absolute position with bottom: 0px; working, of course all 
my Divs are drawn on top of one another

```
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|I                    |
-----------------------
```

What I want is to have something like this, so I can then change the sizes of my divs and make my column graph.

```
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII|
-----------------------
```

Which is of course possible via styling them individually, or via JS, and probably what I'll end up doing. But is there a good HTML-CSS-only way of doing this?

```
.Column {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1%;
}

.Graph {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 3px solid green;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use javascript to calculate the position and set the `right` property of the style?

Comment: You also could wrap the divs in another div, the divs will be floated where as the wrapping div will be absolute-positioned to the bottom of its parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox to achieve this:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid;
  align-items:flex-end;
}
.container > span {
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  margin:0 5px;
}
.container > span:nth-child(odd) {
  background:blue;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Or some inline-block tricks:

```css
.container {
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.container:before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
.container > span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  margin:0 5px;
}
.container > span:nth-child(odd) {
  background:blue;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm ant it's really elegant! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I believe you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/n172eubg/3/

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#parent {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.child {
  postion: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0px 7px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edits After discussion**

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}


#parent {
 position: absolute;
  
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 5%;
  
 height: 300px;
 width: 90%;
 
 border: 2px solid #000;
}

.child {
 postion: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 
 height: 10%;
 width: 10%; 
  
 margin: 0px 7px;
 border: 2px solid blue;
}

.height2 {
   height: 20%;
}

.height3 {
   height: 30%;
}

.height4 {
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
   <div class="child height2"></div>
   <div class="child height2"></div>
   <div class="child height2"></div>
   <div class="child height3"></div>
   <div class="child height3"></div>
   <div class="child height3"></div>
   <div class="child height4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this really wouldn't work for me since I want to then be able change the height values of the bottom attatched divs with props to display data. I need them to reach all the way up to the top of the container you have created if necessary. It's a column chart after all.

Comment: What if you change `#parent` height from `100px` to `100%` ?
And If you need them to fill the whole container why position them at the bottom ?

Comment: Changing the parent height to 100% and then loweing the percentage of the child elements effectively recreates the original problem (where they are ankered on top, and where I change them to absolute position to anker them on bottom, they overlap). What I want is to have is multiple of the same child elements ankered to the bottom of the parent div element so that I can pass props individually to each one and change only its height (while still being ankered to the bottom). The result should work like a column chart like this https://www.meta-chart.com/share/untitled-39562

Comment: Yeap so the original solution i posted would work for this, ill make some edits to hopefully show this in a better way.

Comment: @ΘεοδώρητοςΜπιζμπιάνος Did the edits i make help at all?

Comment: Yes this solution really could work for me as well now that I had some time to play with it, thanks a lot for your time. However align-items: flex-end is exactly what I am describing in my original post. I really do prefer this solution.